# Error with font_size when adding items to scroll view in kivy dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Hello I'm relatively new to kivy. I'm making a weather app and Im trying to add multiple banners (MDBoxLayout) for every hour using a for loop from the py file instead of creating 24 MDBoxLayout in kv file. so I made hourly_banner class in python file but the problem is that the font_size doesnt have any affect and I dont know how to make change the size of everything so it fits. I have the comparison picture below. Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

py file

```
class hourly_banner(MDBoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.adaptive_height = True
        self.orientation = "horizontal"
        super(hourly_banner, self).__init__()
        with self.canvas:
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
        self.bind(pos=self.update_rect, size=self.update_rect)


        time_label = MDLabel(size_hint_x=0.15, text=kwargs['time'], font_size= self.height*0.12)
        weather_icon = MDIcon(size_hint_x=0.1, icon=kwargs['weather_icon'], font_size=self.height*0.12)
        temp_label = MDLabel(size_hint_x=0.14, text=kwargs['temp'], font_size= self.height*0.15)
        weather_code_label= MDLabel(size_hint_x=0.5, text=kwargs['weather_code'], font_size=self.height*0.125)
        precip_layout = MDBoxLayout(adaptive_height=True, size_hint_x=0.2)
        precip_layout_icon = MDIcon(icon=kwargs['precip_icon'], font_size=self.height*0.15)
        precip_layout_label = MDLabel(text=kwargs['precip_percent'], font_size=self.height*0.125)
        precip_layout.add_widget(precip_layout_icon)
        precip_layout.add_widget(precip_layout_label)

        self.add_widget(time_label)
        self.add_widget(weather_icon)
        self.add_widget(temp_label)
        self.add_widget(weather_code_label)
        self.add_widget(precip_layout)

class MyApp(MDApp):
   

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "LightBlue"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "700"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")


    def on_start(self):

        self.menu_1 = self.create_menu(
            "Button menu", self.root.ids['site_screen'].ids['toolbar'].ids['button_1'])
        self.menu_2 = self.create_menu(
            "Button dots", self.root.ids['site_screen'].ids['toolbar'].ids['button_2'])

        hourly_grid = self.root.ids["site_screen"].ids['hourly_grid']
        for i in range(20):
            H = hourly_banner(time='12PM', weather_icon="weather-sun", temp="48", weather_code="Mostly Coudly",
                              precip_icon='water-percent', precip_percent="38%")
            hourly_grid.add_widget(H)
```

kv file:

```
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                id: second_icon
                on_leave:
                    second_icon.icon = "clock-time-four-outline"
                on_tab_press:
                    second_icon.icon = "clock-time-four"
                    #toolbar.title = "Second"
                    toolbar.label.text = "Second"

                #text: "Forecast"
                name: "site_hourly_screen"
                icon: "clock-time-four-outline"

                #Content
                MDScrollViewRefreshLayout:
                    id: refresh_layout_hourly
                    refresh_callback: app.refresh_callback_hourly
                    root_layout: root
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
                    size_hint: 0.9, 1
                    #padding: 10
                    MDGridLayout:
                        id: hourly_grid
                        cols: 1
                        adaptive_height: True
                        padding: 0, "20dp"
                        row_default_height: "50dp"
                        row_force_default: True
                        MDBoxLayout:
                            adaptive_height: True
                            orientation: 'horizontal'

                            MDLabel:
                                size_hint_x: 0.15
                                text: "12PM"
                                font_size: self.height*0.12
                            MDIcon:
                                size_hint_x: 0.1
                                icon: "weather-sunny"
                                font_size: self.height*0.15
                            MDLabel:
                                size_hint_x: 0.14
                                text: "48"
                                font_size: self.height*0.125
                            MDLabel:
                                size_hint_x: 0.5
                                text: "freezing_rain_heavy"
                                font_size: self.height * 0.125
                            MDBoxLayout:
                                adaptive_height: True
                                size_hint_x: 0.2
                                MDIcon:
                                    icon: "water-percent"
                                    font_size: self.height*0.15
                                MDLabel:
                                    text: "38%"
                                    font_size: self.height*0.125

                        MDBoxLayout:
                            adaptive_height: True
                            orientation: 'horizontal'

                            MDLabel:
                                size_hint_x: 0.15
                                text: "12PM"
                                font_size: self.height*0.12
                            MDIcon:
                                size_hint_x: 0.1
                                icon: "weather-sunny"
                                font_size: self.height*0.15
                            MDLabel:
                                size_hint_x: 0.145
                                text: "48"
                                font_size: self.height*0.125
                            MDLabel:
                                size_hint_x: 0.45
                                text: "freezing_rain_heavy"
                                font_size: self.height * 0.125
                            MDBoxLayout:
                                adaptive_height: True
                                size_hint_x: 0.2
                                MDIcon:
                                    icon: "water-percent"
                                    font_size: self.height*0.15
                                MDLabel:
                                    text: "38%"
                                    font_size: self.height*0.125

                        MDBoxLayout:
                            adaptive_height: True
                            orientation: 'horizontal'

                            MDLabel:
                                size_hint_x: 0.15
                                text: "12PM"
                                font_size: self.height*0.12
                            MDIcon:
                                size_hint_x: 0.1
                                icon: "weather-sunny"
                                font_size: self.height*0.15
                            MDLabel:
                                size_hint_x: 0.145
                                text: "48"
                                font_size: self.height*0.125
                            MDLabel:
                                size_hint_x: 0.45
                                text: "freezing_rain_heavy"
                                font_size: self.height * 0.125
                            MDBoxLayout:
                                adaptive_height: True
                                size_hint_x: 0.2
                                MDIcon:
                                    icon: "water-percent"
                                    font_size: self.height*0.15
                                MDLabel:
                                    text: "38%"
                                    font_size: self.height*0.125
```

Comparison Image:
[Implementing from kv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRN9e.png) vs [Implementing from python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOuWR.png)

Comment: your code is not complete because when i run it i find other error about  about this _self.menu_1_ and _app.refresh_callback_hourly_

Comment: Sorry I didn't upload the complete code because the complete code is fairly large, I forgot to comment those two things but it has no relation with the banner function. The kv file is not the entire kv file either but that's the section I'm adding the widget too

Answer (score 0):

this's the issue

```
time_label = MDLabel(size_hint_x=0.15, text=kwargs['time'], font_size= self.height*0.12)
```

in this line self refer to the `MDBoxLayout` not to the label just like in the kv file
here is refer to MDLabel and that's why the font size is different

```
MDLabel:
    size_hint_x: 0.15
    text: "12PM"
    font_size: self.height*0.12
```

the solution is to use custom MDlabel in the python file
in python file add this

```
class CustomMDLabel(MDLabel):
    pass
```

in the kv file

```
<CustomMDLabel>: 
    size_hint_x: 0.15
    font_size: self.height*0.12
```

and use it in the hourly_banner class instead of the normal `MDLabel`
like this

```
 time_label = CustomMDLabel(text=kwargs['time'])
```